# How to get the outline of the image detected (using cnn object detection) rather than rectangular box around it?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I have been googling for 1 week about object detection. What everyone show is similar to the below image.
[image]

But  I don't want square boxes around the detected object. I need the rough outline of the object as shown in the below image. 
[image]

Is it possible? If possible please give a brief explanation about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for semantic segmentation. Object detection usually means finding a bounding box and a label for an object, while semantic segmentation is the problem of assigning a class label to each pixel in an image. Once you have the class labels for each pixel, you can use a classical contour detection algorithm to find the outline of the object. [Matlab docs](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/semantic-segmentation-basics.html) have a nice explainer on semantic segmentation.

Below is an example output of a semantic segmentation model trained on a self-driving car dataset:

[image]

Image by [Vladlen Koltun](http://vladlen.info/publications/feature-space-optimization-for-semantic-video-segmentation/)